# Laravel: how to import a sql file through phpmyadmin after you created a schema without throwing a constraint exception?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, laravel-5

Hi I have the following schema code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('states', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('acronym');
        $table->string('name');
    });

    Schema::create('cities', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states');
    });

    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('states');
    Schema::drop('cities');
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

The migration works fine, now I want to import a sql file through phpmyadmin, but I receive the following error:
1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yearbook`.`cities`, CONSTRAINT `cities_state_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `states` (`id`))
Before making the migration it worked fine, so I'd like to know if there is a way to import the file without removing the foreign keys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration is fine and the problem is in your data.

Since you have added foreign key constraint then state with this id must exist before you can import cities.

Right now you have states id autoincrementing so you need to overwrite it or be absolutely sure it gets correct ID from insert order.